# Maintaining pandas index while melting a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe df with 3 column names and a date index (example below:)

```
First    |A              |
Second   |B      |b      |
Third    |C  |c  |C  |c  |
Date 
31/12/20 |1  |4  |7  |20 |
01/01/21 |2  |5  |8  |21 |
02/01/21 |3  |6  |9  |22 |
```

I'm trying to turn it from a 'wide' to a 'long' dataset before exporting to csv and want to maintain 'Date' as the index. Using:

`pd.melt(df)`

I get:

```
   |First |Second |Third |value
0  |A     |B      |C     |1
1  |A     |B      |C     |2
2  |A     |B      |C     |3
....
10 |A     |b      |c     |20
11 |A     |b      |c     |21
12 |A     |b      |c     |22
```

While my target output is:

```
Date      |First |Second |Third |value
31/12/20  |A     |B      |C     |1
01/01/21  |A     |B      |C     |2
02/01/21  |A     |B      |C     |3
....
31/12/20  |A     |b      |c     |20
01/01/21  |A     |b      |c     |21
02/01/21  |A     |b      |c     |22
```

Searching I've tried `pd.melt(df.reset_index())` unsuccessfully and haven't come across a solution, which I think must be straightforward!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible add parameter `ignore_index=False` to [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = df.melt(ignore_index=False)
print (df)
         First Second Third  value
Date                              
31/12/20     A      B     C      1
01/01/21     A      B     C      2
02/01/21     A      B     C      3
31/12/20     A      B     c      4
01/01/21     A      B     c      5
02/01/21     A      B     c      6
31/12/20     A      b     C      7
01/01/21     A      b     C      8
02/01/21     A      b     C      9
31/12/20     A      b     c     20
01/01/21     A      b     c     21
02/01/21     A      b     c     22
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack(level=[0,1,2]).reset_index(name='value')
print (df)
        Date First Second Third  value
0   31/12/20     A      B     C      1
1   31/12/20     A      B     c      4
2   31/12/20     A      b     C      7
3   31/12/20     A      b     c     20
4   01/01/21     A      B     C      2
5   01/01/21     A      B     c      5
6   01/01/21     A      b     C      8
7   01/01/21     A      b     c     21
8   02/01/21     A      B     C      3
9   02/01/21     A      B     c      6
10  02/01/21     A      b     C      9
11  02/01/21     A      b     c     22
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried both and neither work, I get an unexpected 'ignore_index' and 'name'. However I did get stack to work using: 

df = df.stack(level=[0, 1, 2]).rename_axis(index {None:'var_name'}) .rename('value').reset_index()

Comment: @Oli_B Reason is old pandas version, if upgrade all working well.